# Add checkboxes in a column automatically when another column contains a value (or not) in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

I need to automatically add checkboxes in column `F` but only when column `G` contains a value in the same row.
Conversely, I want a checkbox to disappear or be disabled when the cell in column `G` in the same row is emptied.

A search of Stack Exchange does not show suitable solutions. Tried using an `onEdit(e)` script to create and delete checkboxes but that failed.

How do I easily add and remove checkboxes in rows depending on whether column `G` contains a value or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Option 1: conditional formatting

Use conditional formatting to set the text color of checkboxes to white to make them invisible when the cell in column `G` in the same row is blank. An invisible checkbox cannot be toggled accidentally by clicking it — Sheets will issue a warning if that happens. Note that you can still toggle a checkbox by selecting the checkbox cell and pressing Space.

You can automatically make checkboxes invisible when column `G` is blank by applying this conditional formatting custom formula rule to the checkbox range `F2:F`:

```
=isblank(G2)
```

With this formatting, the checkboxes only become visible when a value is inserted in column `G` in the same row.

### Option 2: an `onEdit()` script

You can also add and remove checkboxes with a script like this:

```
/**
* Simple trigger that runs each time the user hand edits the spreadsheet.
* Inserts and removes checkboxes depending on whether another column is blank.
*
* @param {Object} e The onEdit() event object.
*/
function onEdit(e) {
  // version 1.2, written by --Hyde, 26 March 2024
  //  - see https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/153531/269219
  if (!e) throw new Error('Please do not run the onEdit(e) function in the script editor window.');
  try {
    const specs = [
      {
        sheet: /^(Sheet1|Sheet2|Sheet3)$/i,
        column: 3,
        checkboxes: {
          rowStart: 2,
          rowEnd: 13,
          columnStart: 12,
          columnEnd: 42,
        },
      },
    ];
    let sheet;
    const spec = specs.find(spec =>
      spec.column === e.range.columnStart
      && spec.checkboxes.rowStart <= e.range.rowEnd
      && spec.checkboxes.rowEnd >= e.range.rowStart
      && (sheet || (sheet = e.range.getSheet())).getName().match(spec.sheet)
    );
    if (!spec) return;
    const rowStart = Math.max(spec.checkboxes.rowStart, e.range.rowStart);
    const rowEnd = Math.min(spec.checkboxes.rowEnd, e.range.rowEnd);
    const numRows = rowEnd - rowStart + 1;
    const numColumns = spec.checkboxes.columnEnd - spec.checkboxes.columnStart + 1;
    const checkboxCells = sheet.getRange(rowStart, spec.checkboxes.columnStart, numRows, numColumns);
    if (e.value) {
      checkboxCells.insertCheckboxes();
    } else {
      checkboxCells.clearDataValidations();
      checkboxCells.clearContent();
    }
  } catch (error) {
    e.source.toast(error.messsage);
    throw error;
  }
}
```

This approach has the benefit over the invisible checkboxes described in option 1 that checkboxes only get inserted when required, which prevents accidentally toggling an invisible checkbox by pressing Space in a seemingly empty cell.